# Why can I no longer push or pull from my repo after changing its name?

Tags: git, github

I changed the name of my repo, then did a `git remote set-url...` to the new SSH URL in the repo, but now I can't push or pull. I tried to do `ssh -vT git@github.com` as part of the [troubleshooting guide on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey) and that seems to fail as well, ending with this:

```
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/selig/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/selig/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
MacBook-Air:.ssh selig$ ls -la /Users/selig/.ssh/
total 8
drwx------   3 selig  staff   102 16 Feb 13:39 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 35 selig  staff  1190 18 Jul 19:50 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 selig  staff   821 18 Jul 19:49 known_hosts
MacBook-Air:.ssh selig$
```

Comment: Are your pubkeys still set correctly? Are you certain the new URL is correct?

Comment: Why would they change/how do I set them? And I copied and pasted the URL, and just double checked, so yes.

Comment: In the troubleshooting guide you linked, they point out that *the "Trying private key" lines also indicate that no file was found. If a file existed, those lines would be "Offering private key".* Do private keys exist at the path specified?

Comment: I added in the original post the files in that directory. Is that what you mean?

Comment: renaming a repo and "the problem" appear to be unrelated.

Comment: there are no public keys in your .ssh folder. have you set up keys at some point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to have any SSH keypairs with which to authenticate to GitHub. You need to follow the steps in the [Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) guide on GitHub. It explains how to get SSH authentication working with Git for use with GitHub.

You can choose to provide a passphrase when generating your key (which will prompt you every time you push), or you can leave the passphrase blank. If you do not assign a passphrase to the keypair, make absolutely certain that nobody ever gets your private key (the `id_rsa` file) or else they will be able to authenticate as you without having to know your passphrase.